# Admob Asking me to Verify Twice

Tags: admob

ad-mob asked me to verify my identity by Id(national identity card, drivers license or international passport) as the only option (without putting option for pin verification) and I did yesterday. The account was verified and ads was restored. 6 hours later they are asking me to verify by Pin.but ads are still displaying, I thought you only verify with one means of verification. Why do i have to do both or is this an error on ad-mob side. if so provide me with a link for ad-mob support team, i cant seem to find one on the ad-mob or Google page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. You have verified ID by uploading your document now you need to verify address. A letter will come from Google by post to your given address, it will contain a PIN, you need to enter that pin so that your address is verified.

That's all after that you need to provide bank account to receive payment once you reach payment threshold.

It's hard to contact AdMob for the new publishers. You can post in [AdMob Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/google-admob-ads-sdk/android) some contributor will answer

Comment: Thanks for replying @ Pradeep Behera. Postal service in my country is really bad  what if the pin does not show up after 3 attempts?

Comment: An option with other verification method will appear in your account. Don't worry.